# Is there a way to use CSS position sticky with Quarto?

Tags: css, quarto

I would like to use the `CSS` `position` `sticky` with `Quarto`, but it does not seem to be working. Below is a reprex to demonstrate that the `h1.title` element does not stick to the top of the page as expected. I believe the `position` `sticky` may not be working because of the `overflow` set by Quarto's CSS, but I cannot figure out how to change the `overflow` so that the `position` `sticky` works. I tried to change the `overflow` to `auto` manually in DevTools, but to no avail. The sticky position works with no issue in a normal html document as you can see [here](https://codepen.io/novotny1akub/pen/YzLLmmJ).

````
---
format:
  html:
    self-contained: true
---

```{ojs}
//| echo: false


html`<style> h1.title {position: sticky; top: 0;} </style>`


html `
<h1 class="title">Custom CSS</h1>

<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
`
```
````

Comment: Do you need to write html inside the ojs chunk?

Comment: @shafee in my real usecase, I use an advanced Tabulator.js table and an advanced chart using Vega-Lite so I do not use html per se.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about quarto-generated HTML output, whatever gets generated from a code chunk (`ojs chunk` in this case) is wrapped with two consecutive div with classes `cell` and `cell-output-display`.

And the class `cell-output-display` has the css property `overflow-x` set as `auto`, which is the main reason for `position: sticky` not working (which you have already guessed).

So to solve it, we just need to unset that property.

**quarto-doc.qmd**

````
---
format:
  html:
    self-contained: true
---

<style>
  .sticky-chunk .cell-output-display {
    overflow-x: unset !important;
}
</style>


::: {.sticky-chunk}

```{ojs}
//| echo: false


html`<style> h1.title {position: sticky; top: 0;} </style>`


html `
<h1 class="title">Custom CSS</h1>

<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
<h1>h1</h1>
`
```

:::
````

(Note that, I have used pandoc divs just to define a class so that we can overwrite that property for a specific chunk)